# jquery popup is not working

Tags: jquery

i want to open a pop in my mvc3 razor application for that i am witting following  code .
When i click button .nothing happen . and i see a error in Error console " $(#dialog).dialog is not a function ".  I am new to jquery , can any one help me what mistake i am doing.

```
 $(function () {   
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'hi there',
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                //Load the Edit action which will return 
                // the partial view _Edit
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit")");
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

Comment: why you give $('#dialog').dialog( ) two times..will you explain please

Comment: call this function immediatly after the document.ready, it will 
work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `.dialog` you have to load jQuery and jQueryUI on your page.

Add this to your `HEAD`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i have included this library in my page ,even then the same error is coming." <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"

Comment: i have include the above links .this time no error in error console but still nothing happen when i click button.